# MST that crosses a graph cut exactly N times

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Given two connected weighted graphs and a set of pairs of vertices that can "cross the river" between the two graphs, the task is to find an MST (minimum spanning tree) of a graph made of both graphs connected with the crossings that contains exactly N crossings over the river. The solution to a given arrangement always exists.

In the example below, the left graph has vertices (0, 1, 2, 3) and the right one (4, 5, 6, 7, 8). The edges 3-4, 3-5, 2-4, 2-5 are to be chosen from and N = 2. The minimum spanning tree that contains exactly two crossings over the river is depicted in red.

[image: Example]

First of all by the cut property of MSTs, I think that the crossings to be chosen are the N lowest ones.

Secondly, how do you force, say Primm's algorithm to choose some edges when trying to find an MST? You can't just connect the chosen crossings beforehand as it will probably choose just one.

First, my idea was to modify it such that it always chooses the chosen crossings (3-5 and 2-4 in the picture above) during the process, but that could create a loop, right? It has to somehow know not to create a loop when forcefully chosing some vertices.

My second idea was to find MSTs for the left and the right side and only then try to connect them - wouldn't that possibly create a loop though? What if you just break the loop with the largest value edge? Wouldn't that automatically yield the answer? You would have it assurred that both sides have their MSTs, those are connected with the cheapest paths and there is no cycle.

Comment: I believe your first intuition is correct. Select edges from the river edges according to Kruskal's algorithm, up to a count of N. This avoids loops and provides the minimal sum among those edges. Then, construct the rest of the MST following the same algorithm, but taking all the other edges into account, instead of the river edges. I am not posting an answer because I am not 100% sure this is correct and sadly lack time today to prove it.

Comment: And when it comes to your other ideas: 1) forcing Prim's algorithm to select certain edges in any way other than limiting the set of vertices may prove difficult to implement efficiently. I do not know if it is possible in a reasonable complexity. 2) If you first found an MST for one side, then the other, then connected them, that would force N to always be 0. 3) Braking loops by removing the heaviest edge on a loop is probably a pretty hard problem as well.

Comment: The first intuition is wrong.  For example, change the edge weighted 9 to weight 2. Then choosing river crossing edges 2 and 6 forces you to enter the right graph through node 4. If you change the edges out of node 4 from weight 4 to 400, and 5 to 500, it's immediately obvious that crossing the river with edges 7 and 2 is going to be far better than crossing with edges 6 and 2.

Comment: Seems tricky. You might be able to do it in polynomial time with weighted matroid intersection, but surely there's a better way...

Comment: Your example graph is incorrect. The red lines aren't an MST. E.g., the edge (3,5) could be replaced with (4,6). Now you only have one river crossing but reduced edge weight. Can you clarify for the question whether 1) you want the minimum weighted spanning tree that includes exactly the required river crossings (which may weigh more than an unrestricted MST), or 2) you know that among all MSTs, at least one includes exactly the required river crossings?

Comment: You can indeed use weighted matroid intersection to get a poly-time algorithm. The first matroid is the spanning tree matroid (of course); the second matroid is a partition matroid that limits the number of non-crossing edges to |V|-1-n.

Comment: Let me back up for a second: do you actually need a spanning *tree*, or just the minimum spanning subgraph with exactly k crossings (which in general may weigh less than the minimum spanning tree with exactly k crossings)?

Comment: N is given and it has to be a minimum spanning tree of of the entire thing with exactly N crossings. In the example, N = 2, so I had to choose two crossings.

Comment: @user3386109 Damn, you're right. Given the edited graph, if we somehow took into consideration 4's cost of entering the graph, we might edit the choosing process such that it takes care of this scenario I suppose. I have no idea how though.

Comment: I think I found the way of finding the MST given N selected crossings - just add them to the new graph and add them to a group before running Kruskal's algorithm and it makes sure to check that there are no loops by itself. It crashes if you can't make an MST with given path selections (if it would always make a cycle). About the paths - I resorted to testing all possible combinations of paths - there seems to be no way of speeding it up.

Comment: Yup, this is one of those problems that seems simple on the surface, but is apparently diabolically hard. (I say "apparently" because I don't know enough about matroids to evaluate @DavidEisenstat's claim that there's a poly-time solution.) Selecting N crossings, and seeding Kruskal's with the trees formed by the crossings, seems like an approach that will give a correct solution. However, the number of times you need to run Kruskal's increases exponentially with the number of crossings, e.g. choosing 2 crossings out of 4 requires 6 runs, but 20 out of 40 is 138e9.

Comment: Yes but you can divide up both sides into strongly connected components, calculate their MST and connect them to the rest of the graph as vertices with an edge of the calculated MST price. You make the graphs on the sides possibily a lot smaller and it makes the recomputing of the whole MST more managable, albeit asymptotically the same.

Comment: Agreed, there are some results that can be reused, especially in the simple example with 2 crossings. This hints of dynamic programming, but I haven't found a clean solution that exploits that.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s an algorithm that’s simpler than weighted matroid intersection. Letting C be the set of crossing edges, it runs in time O((|E| + k |C|) log |V|) assuming an efficient implementation using dynamic trees. (I’m sandbagging the running time a bit; you could use a better initialization algorithm than Prim or Kruskal.)

The problem is:

> min<sub>x</sub> ∑<sub>e∈E</sub> w<sub>e</sub> x<sub>e</sub>
> subject to
> (*) ∑<sub>e∈C</sub> x<sub>e</sub> = k
> x ∈ {0,1}<sup>E</sup> indicates a spanning tree

Except for the constraint marked (*), this is a classic minimum spanning tree problem. Let’s reformulate (*) using a Lagrange multiplier, λ.

> min<sub>x</sub> max<sub>λ</sub> ∑<sub>e∈E</sub> w<sub>e</sub> x<sub>e</sub> + λ (∑<sub>e∈C</sub> x<sub>e</sub> − k)
> subject to
> x ∈ {0,1}<sup>E</sup> indicates a spanning tree
> λ ∈ **R**

Intuitively, we choose x, and an adversary responds by choosing λ. If we choose fewer than k crossing edges, then the adversary trashes the objective as λ → −∞. If we choose more than k crossing edges, then the adversary trashes the objective as λ → ∞. Thus it behooves us to choose exactly k crossing edges.

This problem has a dual problem:

> max<sub>λ</sub> min<sub>x</sub> ∑<sub>e∈E</sub> w<sub>e</sub> x<sub>e</sub> + λ (∑<sub>e∈C</sub> x<sub>e</sub> − k)
> subject to
> x ∈ {0,1}<sup>E</sup> indicates a spanning tree
> λ ∈ **R**

Here the adversary chooses λ, and we respond by choosing x. Intuitively, this should be strictly better for us, but for interesting mathematical reasons, with perfect play, it’s exactly the same. Now, the trick is that we can take the multiplier λ and fold its contribution (except for λ k, which is constant in x) into the weights w, giving us back a standard minimum spanning tree problem.

### Algorithm

This is a kinetic algorithm. Initialize it with a minimum spanning tree, considering the edges of E ∖ C from lightest to heaviest followed by the edges of C from lightest to heaviest. This is the minimum spanning tree in the limit as λ → ∞. If it has more than k crossing edges, then there is no solution; this spanning tree has as few crossing edges as possible. We maintain the minimum spanning tree as we slide λ towards −∞, stopping when either there are exactly k crossing edges (optimal solution) or we reach the limit (no solution).

As usual, we don’t literally change λ by small increments. Instead, we look for the next value of λ where “something interesting happens”, i.e., find the maximum λ such that there exists an edge e ∈ C not in the current spanning tree and an edge e′ in E ∖ C in its fundamental cycle such that w(e) + λ = w(e′). We remove e′ from the spanning tree in favor of e. Data-structurally, a dynamic tree is (in theory) an efficient way to make these operations fast. For at most k times, we loop over e ∈ C and make an O(log |V|)-time query for each one, followed by two O(log |V|)-time topological changes.